# Pandas .groups AttributeError: 'DataFrame' has no attribute 'groups

Tags: python, pandas

I have a grouped DataFrame and I'm wanting to get the groups so I can iterate over them later, but .groups is returning `AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'groups'`

```
test = temp.groupby(['global company key','calendar year'])[['columnA','columnB', 'columnC']].sum()
```

Example of data:

```
                                   columnA     columnB     columnC
global company key  calendar year  
          1109          2010            20          30          20
          1109          2011            11          10          13
          1468          2010            50          10          16
          1468          2011             1           3           7
```

What I tried running:

```
test.groups
```

Am I doing something wrong? From the documentation, this should be extremely easy.

Comment: is the 'example of data' a temp DF? to which you're applying groupby?

Comment: No, I assigned the groupby to the variable test.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When using group by, the object returned is a `GroupBy` object, which has the `groups` attribute that you used. BUT when applying any function on top of the `Groupby` object (sum() in your case) it changes back to a `pd.DataFrame` which does not have the `.groups`.

The alternative approach is to transform your dataframe to an iterable (`df.to_dict()` for example and then iterate over it.

Comment: Ahhhh okay, thank you for explaining that!